# window.webkit.messageHandlers is null on ios 15

Tags: ios, swift

window.webkit.messageHandlers gives null on ios 15, but when I set
`config.limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains = true;`  it works properly.

But I don't want to restrict my WkWebView to certain domains.

Code -

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()

    userContentController.add(WKSMH, name: "print")
    userContentController.add(WKSMH, name: "push-subscribe")
    userContentController.add(WKSMH, name: "push-permission-request")
    userContentController.add(WKSMH, name: "push-permission-state")
    userContentController.add(WKSMH, name: "setUserAttribute")
    config.userContentController = userContentController
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        config.limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains = true;
    }
    config.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "standalone")
    
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: calcWebviewFrame(webviewView: container, toolbarView: nil), configuration: config)
```

Is there any way to use messageHandlers other than using `config.limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains = true` ?

Comment: Setting that property to true fixed my issue of messageHandles being null as well but i'm equally confused as to why...

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be in [this webkit article](https://webkit.org/blog/10882/app-bound-domains/).

If you have the `WKAppBoundDomains` key defined in your project's `Info.plist` file, then all WKWebViews within your app will have some features disabled unless that flag is set to true.

> Once the WKAppBoundDomains key is added to the Info.plist, all
> WKWebView instances in the application default to a mode where
> JavaScript injection, custom style sheets, cookie manipulation, and
> message handler use is denied. To gain back access to these APIs, a
> WKWebView can set the limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains flag in their
> WKWebView configuration, like so:
>
> webViewConfiguration.limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains = YES;
>
> Setting this flag indicates to WebKit that a WKWebView will only
> navigate to app-bound domains

So if you don't want to have to set that flag, try removing the `WKAppBoundDomains` key from your `Info.plist` file.